# Codeigniter duplicate elements from the database

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I've got a page that contains 4 products loaded from the database, when you scroll down you get 4 more products every time.

This products are loaded in a random way, the problem are the duplicate products.

This is the line that I used into the model:

```
$this->db->order_by('productID', 'RANDOM');
```

Without this line everything works fine.
I can't use `limit` set to 1 because I've got:

```
$query = $this->db->get('product', 4, $offset);
```

There's a simple way to solve this problem? I've to do an array that contains all the products?

UPDATE

This is the script into the index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var products = <?= $get_products ?>;
    var loaded_products = 0;

    $(".loadMoreProducts").click(function(){
        loaded_products += 4;

        var dati = "welcome/get_products/" + loaded_products;

        $.ajax({
          url:'welcome/get_products/' + loaded_products,
          type: 'get',
          data: dati,
          cache: false,
          success: function() {

            $.get(dati, function(data){
                $("#mainContainerProductWelcome").append(data);
            });

            if(loaded_products >= products - 4) {
                $(".loadMoreProducts").hide();
            } else {
                // load more still visible
            }
          },
          error: function() {
            // there's something wrong
          }
        });

        // show spinner on ajax request starts
        $(".loading-spinner").ajaxStart(function(){
            $(".loading-spinner").show();
            $(".text-load").hide();
        });

        // ajax request complets hide spinner
        $(".loading-spinner").ajaxStop(function(){
            $(".loading-spinner").delay(5000).hide();
            $(".text-load").show();
        });

        return false;
    });

    // submit form contact
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
        loaded_products += 4;

        var dati = "welcome/get_products/" + loaded_products;

        $.ajax({
          url:'welcome/get_products/' + loaded_products,
          type: 'get',
          data: dati,
          cache: false,
          success: function() {

            $.get(dati, function(data){
                $("#mainContainerProductWelcome").append(data);
            });

            if(loaded_products >= products - 4) {
                $(".loadMoreProducts").hide();
            } else {
                // load more still visible
            }
          },
          error: function() {
            // there's something wrong
          }
        });

        // show spinner on ajax request starts
        $(".loading-spinner").ajaxStart(function(){
            $(".loading-spinner").show();
            $(".text-load").hide();
        });

        // ajax request complets hide spinner
        $(".loading-spinner").ajaxStop(function(){
            $(".loading-spinner").delay(5000).hide();
            $(".text-load").show();
        });
        return false;
    }
});

});
</script>
```

controller:

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $data['description'] = "Description";
    $data['keywords'] = "Keywords";
    $data['products'] = $this->abitainterni->getAllProductsLimit();
    $data['get_products'] = $this->abitainterni->get_products();
    //load view
    $this->load->view('welcome', $data);
}

function get_products($offset)
{
    $data['products'] = $this->abitainterni->getAllProductsLimit($offset);
    $this->load->view('get_products', $data);
}
```

model:

```
function getAllProductsLimit($offset=0)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM product P";
    $this->db->order_by('productPosition','ASC');
    $query = $this->db->get('product', 4, $offset);
  if($query->num_rows() > 0){
    return $query->result();
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

function get_products()
{
    $query = $this->db->count_all_results('product');
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the entire query? I mean, activate the profiler and post the complete query used to get the products.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make an array of received ProducstIDs

For eg:, In the first run, you got productIDs as (1,5,8,9)

Do as follows.

```
$exlude_ids= 1,5,8,9;

$this->db->where_not_in('productID',$exlude_ids);
```

in next time, add those ids to exclude_ids and continue looping.

I've done this on one website. So if you need more help, just comment on it.

**EDIT**

**CONTROLLER :**

After fetching the first four product rows, add those product_ids into an array and pass this to model as shown below.

eg : `$exlcude_ids = array(1,5,7,3);`

**MODEL :**

```
function getAllProductsLimit($offset=0,$exlude_ids=array())
{
    $this->db->select(*);
    if(count($exclude_ids)>0)
    {
       $this->db->where_not_in('productID',$exlude_ids);
    }
    $this->db->order_by('productPosition','ASC');
    $query = $this->db->get('product', 4, $offset);
  if($query->num_rows() > 0)
  {
    return $query->result();
  }
  else
  {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Now I try to do that. If I can't I would be happy if you help me.

Comment: I've edited my answer please check it. Reply me if you have more questions.. :) I hope this will help you. :)

Comment: What about the controller? I've to explode() `$exclude_ids` and pass it to the model with `$data['products'] = $this->db->getAllProductsLimit($offset,$exclude_ids);` how do you do?

Comment: no need just pass it as an array of productIds recieved. suppose you got 1,6,8,2, pass its as an array

`$exclude_ids = array();
$exlclude_ids[] = 1;
$exlclude_ids[] = 6;
$exlclude_ids[] = 8;
$exlclude_ids[] = 2;`

OR `$exclude_ids = array(1,6,8,2);`

Comment: Can you write the control?

Comment: @SimoneRama, Sorry, I can't understand your control functions... just make and array of product_ids received and pass it to the model... that's easy way.

Comment: what exactly i was looking for :) +1

Answer (score 3):

You should do it like this. When you first run the query set an array.
Now when you get the results( 4 rows) and display the records put the ids of these records in a javascript array. You must be using ajax to scrolldown and fetching more results.
Next time when you want to run query first send the javascript array, to php use json. PHP will get json encoded array .decode it. if its length is equal to 0 then run simple query.else run `WHERE productID NOT IN ($array)`. this way you will be able to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your support, I've updated my question, can you help me to do that?